# AWK command print inversion

Tags: linux, awk

there is some help needed to what comes in... let's say we have the following text into a file

```
aeht
mark
tjae
aejra
ytha
mark 
yeaja
```

so it's gotta start printing until it finds the word `mark`, which will not print but change the behaviour of awk and stop printing the next lines until it spots the second `mark` with which it will start printing again and so on everytime it spots a `mark` the behaviour will change... 
Is it possible? How can this be done?

(the `mark` line should never be printed out)

Comment: In many ways, but firstly show us where you got stuck in your attempts.

Comment: I'm facing problems to the way that it shall change it's behaviour!

Comment: I haven't got anywhere near it yet :(

Comment: how many "mark"s do you have in file? could be more than 3? also if the "mark" will be in output too? if yes, which "mark" should be there?

Comment: This should work not depending on how many marks there are inside, it just should change the way the code prints everytime it finds the word mark. No, mark wont be printed

Comment: @user3214998 alright. the fish is below.

Answer (score 3):

No matter if you want the "mark" in your output or not, this line should give you help:

```
awk -v f=1 '/^mark$/{f*=-1;next}f>0' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat file
1
2
mark
3
4
5
mark
6
7
8
mark
9
10

kent$  awk -v f=1 '/^mark$/{f*=-1;next}f>0' file
1
2
6
7
8
```

Comment: And be careful! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335019/file-copy-script-linux (Kent help)

Comment: @fedorqui thanks..  I read the page you linked, didn't understand what did you mean, until the end of the question... I would edit that question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/mark/{f=!f;next} !f' file
aeht
yeaja
```